# react.js typescript spread(...) adding only the last element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to add an element in an array in react.js

```
this.state.chat_list.map(elem => {
  if (
    elem.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(this.props.searching_username.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  ) {
    this.setState(
      { searched_chat_list: [...this.state.searched_chat_list, elem.name] },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.searched_chat_list);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Here is code.

The problem is **It only adds the last element from the result**

Assume I have `a,ab,c,d,aad` and if I search with `a` it will return only `aad` instead of `a,ab,aad`.

*How can I resolve this?*

Comment: What did you initialize this.state.searched_chat_list to?

Comment: Use `includes` `const list = data.filter(item => item.includes(letter));`

Comment: you should formulate the question more clearly. Is your problem: "how to filter all the items which starts with 'a'?" if it is - the answer is  ```data.filter(a => /a/g.test(a))```

Comment: Why are you using map? What are you mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you want something like this:

```
this.setState(prev => ({
    searched_chat_list: [
        ...prev.searched_chat_list,
        prev.chat_list.filter(el =>
            el.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(this.props.searching_username.toLowerCase())
        ),
    ],
}))
```

There are several things that I corrected:

- If you're filtering, you should use `filter` not `map` (and if you're trying to do a for-each, then use `forEach` not `map`. `map` is for mapping an array to another array, which is not what you're doing here.
- I passed a function to `setState` so that I wasn't using stale state values. The reason your `setState` was only setting the last value is because you kept overwriting the previous value on every iteration of the loop.

For example, imagine you did something like this:

```
// State
const state = {
  myArray: [1, 2]
}

// Let's add this array to the one in state
[3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(num => {
  setState({
    // state.myArray is always [1, 2]
    myArray: [...state.myArray, num]
  })
})
```

What do you think the result here would be? You expect `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, but the result is actually `[1, 2, 6]`.

State is only updated on re-render, so the value of `state.myArray` is ALWAYS `[1, 2]`, even on the last iteration of the loop - because the component hasn't re-rendered yet, so state hasn't updated.

Basically you're doing this:

```
  setState({myArray: [1, 2, 3]})
  setState({myArray: [1, 2, 4]})
  setState({myArray: [1, 2, 5]})
  setState({myArray: [1, 2, 6]})
```

Now can you see why only the last item is added to the array?

If your new state value depends on the previous state value, you should always pass a function to setState:

```
// Let's pass a function to setState this time
[3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(num => {
  setState(prev => ({
    // prev is always the most up-to-date state value
    myArray: [...prev.myArray, num]
  }))
})
```

The `prev` value is always the most up-to-date state value, so the result here would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, which is what we wanted, although in your case, you didn't need to iterate the array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it, Filter First than add:

```
const newList = this.state.chat_list.filter(
  elem =>
    elem.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(this.props.searching_username.toLowerCase()) !== -1
);
this.setState(
  {
    searched_chat_list: [...this.state.searched_chat_list, ...newList]
  },
  () => console.log(this.state.searched_chat_list)
);
```